# Add theme settings field to theme-settings.php in d8 is not working for me

Tags: forms

I followed the [documentation on drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/creating-advanced-theme-settings.) to add a field to the theme-settings.php but there must be a mistake in code.

I have a filed called advertisement and a theme called tv so I tried to copy and paste the code and altered the names where to alter theme the files I created in particular are as follows:

/themes/tv/templates/system/thme-settings.php

```
#}
function tv_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form,      
\Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id = NULL) {
  // Work-around for a core bug affecting admin themes. See issue     
 #943212.
  if (isset($form_id)) {
    return;

$form['tv_advertisement'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Widget'),
    '#default_value' => theme_get_setting('tv_advertisement'),
    '#description'   => t("Place this text in the widget spot on your     
 site."),
  );
}
$tv_advertisement = theme_get_setting('tv_advertisement');
```

in /themes/tv/config/install/tv.settings.yml I put this:

```
tv_advertisement: blue bikeshed
```

My /themes/tv/tv.theme file contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Theme functions
 */

// Include all files from the includes directory.
$includes_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/*.inc';
foreach (glob($includes_path) as $filename) {
  require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/includes/' . basename($filename);
}

 function tv_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
 $variables['tv_advertisement'] =     
 theme_get_setting('tv_advertisement');
 }
```

The last thing I did was

```
drush cr
```

to clear the cache

When I go to the themes settings page there are only the default fieds displayed but the new one does not show up

If anyone has a clue what I am doing wrong and is able to enlighten me I would be very pleased.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this code:

```
  if (isset($form_id)) {
    return;
```

The hook interface of hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter is hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state).

You can remove the third parameter:

```
 $form_id = NULL
```

Comment: even if i remove this the variable still ge's not rendered in a twig.html file  The settings page looks good but if I use {{tv_advertisement}} in a twig file for example there is no rendering of the var

Comment: Did you use it in the template **node.html.twig** or in another template ?  I assume if you put it in the preprocess tv_preprocess_node you only get it in node.html.twig.

Comment: how to get the variable rendered in other templates? What the name suggestions are or how to determine theme by template names?

Comment: You can set your debug variable to true like specified in the Drupal documentation -> https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates and after go to the generated html to see HOOK in comments. Also, you can see theme hook preprocess explanation in the Drupal documentation https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.2.x

Comment: Shorter is better function tv_preprocess_node(&$variables) for node
function tv_preprocess_page(&$variables) for page
function tv_preprocess_field(&$variables) for field

Never thought that this is that simple! :-)